# Regex strings with comments by PHP

Tags: php, regex, comments

There is a string as follows

`` 55:      merge `AAA_CORE.P_EC = aaaa_bbbbbt[5]; //ab b5 //1 aaa aaa ``

I expect the results are

```
55
merge `AAA_CORE.P_EC = aaaa_bbbbbt[5];
//ab b5
//1 aaa aaa
```

I had tried to match all sub string by regex

`\s*(\d+):\s*([^\"]*)\s*((?:\/\/)[^\r\n]*)*`

The results are wrong. How should I do? Thank you

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oZbwRm/1)

Comment: `^\s*(\d+):\s*(.*?)\s*(//.*?)\s*(//.*?)$` ... it's a bit rough and ready and it'll depend very much on how strictly your string will always match that format. (note: you'll need to change the delimiters so it might be more like `preg_match('~^\s*(\d+):\s*(.*?)\s*(//.*?)\s*(//.*?)$~' ...);`

Comment: Looks like you're trying to parse some text following specific rules, but these rules are not crystal clear. Can you give some more precision and context?

Comment: Why use `[^"]*` if there are no double quotes in the string? It grabs all to the string end. You could try `\s*(\d+):\s*([^;]*);\s*(\/\/.*)?` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/oZbwRm/2)) and then split the `trim($matches[3])` with `\s+(?=\/\/)` pattern.